# How to get connection fromJava program to phpMyAdmin database?

Tags: java, php, database, phpmyadmin, database-connection

Is it possible to connect a phpMyAdmin database to a Java-based desktop application who's aim is to just save the data from front-end to the database along with I want to fetch the data from database to the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is possible, but your question needs to be clarified a bit in order to make sense.  First, phpMyAdmin isn't a database, it's a tool for working with mySQL databases.  If you're pointing it at a mySQL database then the answer is yes.

This link is a short tutorial on doing exactly what you need.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-s9g1xtyck

If you're trying to do something other than that, like have a java program update phpMyAdmin, or phpMyAdmin communicate directly with your java program.  It may still be possible, but much more difficult.